# Insert JSON into SQL table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL Table 1:

| id | name | gender | age | country | ambition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter | Male | 20 | Italy | Doctor |
| 2 | Angeli | Female | 30 | Australia | Lawyer |

I want to insert into another table like this method.
Output : SQL Table 2

| id | name | details json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter | {"gender":"Male","age":"20","country":"Italy","ambition":"Doctor"} |
| 2 | Angeli | {"gender":"Female","age":"30","country":"Australia","ambition":"Lawyer"} |

Any suggestions on how to insert multiple records?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why did you want to return what looked like flag fields as key-value pairs *in SQL*? The actual question matters a lot. `key=value, key=value` is a terrible format. SQL can produce XML or JSON that can be easily parsed by any client. Assuming you need to combine flags into a single value in the first place.

Comment: Besides, SQL Server has [sparse columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver16) since 2005 and can return all non-null values in a row using [column sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-column-sets?view=sql-server-ver16). Whatever you were trying to do may already be available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all versions, starting from SQL Server 2016, you may generate the JSON content for each row using `FOR JSON PATH`:

```
SELECT 
   id, name,
   details = (SELECT gender, age,  country, ambition FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
```

Starting from SQL Server 2022, you may use `JSON_OBJECT()`:

```
SELECT 
   id, name,
   details = JSON_OBJECT('gender': gender, 'age': age, 'country': country, 'ambition': ambition)
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
```